# Capturando el gancho que introduce un nuevo producto en woocommerce para actualizar un campo personalizado ACF

Tags: woocommerce

Necesito usar el gancho de creación / actualización de un producto de woocommerce para lanzar una función que actualice un campo personalizado de galería, pero no consigo que ningún gancho me funcione.

He probado con estos:

add_action( 'save_post', 'guarda_galeria_curso_relacionado', 10, 2 );

add_action( 'wp_after_insert_post', 'guarda_galeria_curso_relacionado', 10, 2 );

add_action( 'publish_product', 'guarda_galeria_curso_relacionado', 10,2 );

add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'guarda_galeria_curso_relacionado', 10, 2);

add_action( 'woocommerce_new_product', 'guarda_galeria_curso_relacionado', 10, 2 );

add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_process_product_object', 'guarda_galeria_curso_relacionado' );

add_action( 'acf/save_post', 'guarda_galeria_curso_relacionado', 5);

Ninguno me funciona.

Answer (score 0):

He conseguido capturar el evento con el siguiente gancho y prioridad.

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'copia_imagenes_curso_relacionado', 30, 2 );
function copia_imagenes_curso_relacionado( $post_id, $post ) {
   ...
}
```